# How get maximum from array of string using node js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sql-server, node-mssql

I'm trying to get maximum value from the array of string using node JS.
I have enabled CDC on SQL server, I can get transaction-id of data in the string(converted from binary to string within SQL server itself), after that I'm getting an array of strings like below(I'm just posting array string that's being collected from array of objects)

```
  arr1=  [ '0x000001B1000000900009',
      '0x000001B1000000900009',
      '0x000001B1000000900009',
      '0x000001B1000000900009']
```

If get max from array using the following code

```
Math.max.apply(Math, arrayofobject.map(function(o) { return o.y; }))
```

I get the below output

```
122441614897446930
```

it automatically converts string to a number and get max,
I don't want this way, I want max from the array of string, becasue I need to update nextOffset for CDC.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `arraofobject`

Comment: what is `arraofobject` ... what is the `y` property?

Comment: it's an array of objects, example[{a:'sss'},{a:'ssada'},{a:'asdasda'}] here y is a

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```js
const arr1 = ['0x000001B1000000900016',
  '0x000001B1000000900007',
  '0x000001B1000000900008',
  '0x000001B1000000900009'
]

console.log(arr1.sort().pop())
```